# SSRS escapes single quote twice when checking several values from multivalue parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS 2008 R2. And found situation which seems to me a bug.

I have a shared dataset -

```
SELECT 'value1' AS Value
UNION
SELECT 'value''2'
```

I bind this DS to multivalue parameter. When I check only value'2 from multivalue drop down - I see that in SQL Profiler such parameter is passed

```
@Value=N'value''2' -- Two single quotes
```

When I check both values in profiler I see

```
@Value=N'value1,value''''2' -- Four single quotes
```

My Procedure treats first case correctly.

It seems to me that escape happens twice - first for every value, second for whole string?

Does anyone know the source of such behaviour, Thx in advance!

[Here is the same thread on MS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/58320892-82b0-4d05-b59f-a9da4e436323/#58320892-82b0-4d05-b59f-a9da4e436323)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I experienced a very similar problem - the weirdest part, as you've seen, is that it worked when one parameter was selected but not for multiple parameters.

Anyway, I solved this by passing the parameter to the stored procedure slightly differently - in the `Parameters` section of the dataset use the following expression:

`=Join(Parameters!Value.Value, ",")` substituting your parameter name as appropriate.

This effectively will still pass the same comma delimited string of values but for some reason seems to handle the quotes correctly.

Comment: Thx a lot Ian. Very elegant.